# Xcode Interface Builder Missing navigation

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I'm trying to modify `LaunchScreen.xib` using Xcode by adding `UIImageView` but the toolbar is missing. There's supposed to be a list of UI elements on the bottom right corner of XCode but it's empty here.[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: You can always get it by cmd+shift+L .

Comment: Thanks! Things must have changed in XCode 11.

Comment: yes in new Xcode you can get it by clicking + icon on top right corner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xcode 11 You have to tap  "+" button to the top right corner to show the list of UI components.

[image]